# QuickSort, Algorithms, 4th ed. - [Sedgewick, Wayne]

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

I have some question. During my reading Sedgewick and Wayne book, i found sentences that i can't understand. They write: 
-"In the first instance, we do the two
recursive calls before working on the whole array[they speak about MergeSort]; in the second instance, we do the two recursive calls after working on the whole array[they speak about QuickSort]."
May be somebody explain me the full idea of these two sentences.
With best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences are unnecessarily confusing. Actually, both algorithms work in exactly the same fashion: they A. prepare the subproblems to work on, B. work on the subproblems, recursively invoking self, and C. combine the solutions to subproblems into a full solution to the full problem.

In mergesort the subproblems are prepared by dividing the input list in two halves.

In quicksort they are found by partitioning the input array into two parts containing values that are smaller, and not smaller than a chosen pivot.

The recombination step for mergesort is merging.

The recombination step for quicksort is a  no-op, i.e. doing nothing, because the sorting is done *in place*, on *the same* array.

It so happens that for mergesort the last step is more substantial, and for quicksort - the first one.

Answer (score 4):

It's referring to the order in which work is done in the divide-and-conquer strategy that both Merge and QuickSort use.

Specifically, MergeSort divides the work into smaller chunks and makes recursive calls, then merges the two results together. It calls itself recursively **before** performing the merge step.

QuickSort first finds a pivot and performs a partition by swapping elements, then divides the work into smaller chunks and makes recursive calls. It calls itself recursively **after** performing the partition step.